# How to display two web content on same browser alternatively on click without reloading it?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Actually i have created two page Cordova app. i wish to make them in one page and display the second content only after a click event and then go back to first content as well. but want to load entire page on the first load. In the below example i have created two table of color red and blue.
i want to load entire page , but display only red by default and then blue on click. I want to have all content load at once ,but display only red by default and blue on click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%" bgcolor="red" height =500px>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%" bgcolor="green"height=500px>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table id="pressme" style="width:100%" bgcolor="red" height =500px>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="showme" style="width:100%;display:none;" bgcolor="green"height=500px>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var pressme = document.getElementById('pressme');
var showme = document.getElementById('showme');
pressme.addEventListener('click', function(){
  pressme.style.display = 'none';
  showme.style.display = 'block';
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: 'none'` in second **table**, load the entire page and remove that CSS property after a click event has occurred. Use a CSS **class** for that property.

This is really basic, hope I have understood you properly :)